# Why the Ruby Gems code have certain file that just requires file with same name but the only difference is they have snakecase?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

For our current question, let take this repo as an example.
https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-client/tree/master/lib

In this repo, we can see the following list of files. [image]

The `slack_ruby_client.rb` just has `require 'slack-ruby-client'` in the file. I am seeing similar convention in few other gems as well. Another example is https://github.com/orbit-love/notion-ruby-client/tree/main/lib

Is there something with the logic in here? Can someone please explain me or direct me to any article that talks about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, the default entry point of a gem is commonly the exact same file as the name of the gem, as this follows the hardcoded defaults of bundler. There is also a potential conflict of conventions used in naming gems, ruby files and the mapping to constants (classes, modules, ...) in those files.

At first, when adding a gem as a dependency to your `Gemfile`, bundler may try to automatically require the gem. Here, it uses the name of the gem dependency by default (this can be overridden with the `:require` option).

Because of this, the normal entry point for the `slack-ruby-client` and `notion-ruby-client` gems is named the same as the gem. Bundler is thus able to require the gem code without any further instructions.

Now, there are other ways to require Ruby code than to just rely on bundler autorequiring. Often, developers manually require code to ensure that their dependencies are guaranteed to be loaded, regardless of whether bundler is used or not.

The usual convention when naming ruby code files is to use snake_case names named after the respective class / module defined in the file. A class names `MySpecialClass` would be defined in a file named `my_special_class.rb`

Given that the gem is called `slack-ruby-client` and people being aware of this specific name, they might thus assume that they can or should require the gem as `require "slack_ruby_client"`, assuming that snake_case file names are used here (as would be true most of the case in Ruby). The `slack-ruby-client` gem supports this assumption by providing an appropriately named file which loads the actual module.

Additionally, when manually requiring code, many people assume that they can just require the desired module using its module name converted to snake_case. In the case of the `slack-ruby-client` which provides a `Slack` module,  people may thus assume that they can just use `require "slack"` to load the module.

Accordingly, the gem also provides a file called `slack.rb` which requires the actual entry point for the gem.

In the end, those files are added by gem authors to provide convenience entry points for people assuming various conventions for naming gems and / or files in them in order to provide the correct functionality seamlessly.

Answer (score 3):

Because a lot of programmers don't understand that `slack_ruby_client` and `slack-ruby-client` are not the same thing, and so the authors of the gem provide both files to avoid being flooded with bug reports.

The authors of Nokogiri did the same thing because programmers kept mis-spelling it as `require 'nokogirl'` instead of `require 'nokogiri'` and reporting bugs that it is not working, so the Nokogiri authors just put in a file named `nokogirl.rb` which just contains `require 'nokogiri'`.

Comment: That makes sense. I wasn't aware of that. So this isn't any convention, but to add friendliness to the code. Got that. Btw, I also took my time to look into the Nokogiri gem you mentioned, I could't find any references. Mind sharing ?

Comment: There is an entire separate gem called [nokogirl](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogirl) which just depends on nokogiri without brining any functionality on its own. This helps a different issue, namely people running `gem install nokogirl` in their shell.

Comment: Note that this trick is not 100% transparent. If there is code loading "nokogiri" and other code (perhaps another dependency) loading "nokogirl", the entry point is going to be evaluated twice. It might be idempotent? Perhaps, but not in general, because you precisely rely on Kernel#require own idempotence.

Comment: The remark above is only theoretical. In practice all is tunneled through the same require call, normally.

Comment: @XavierNoria: `require` keeps a cache of paths to avoid double-loading a file, but of course `/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/gems/slack-ruby-client-2.3.1/lib/slack_ruby_client.rb` and `/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/gems/slack-ruby-client-2.3.1/lib/slack-ruby-client.rb` are *not* the same path, therefore, `require` *will* load each of them. BUT!!! If all the one file does is simply `require` the other file, then it will already be in the cache and thus not loaded again. The problem you mention would occur if you make copies of the file.

Comment: Yes, yes. Assuming it only does that (what my second remark says). First remark also says Kernel#require is idempotent.